# Issues with changing text in access 2013 report

Tags: ms-access

I have made changes to text in a sentence in a report.
The changes display correctly in Design View and also in Layout View, but when I display it in print preview the previous text is displayed, not the new amended text. If I then go back to Layout view, it now displays the original text just like print preview did. The display in Design shows the new amended text.

I am using access 2013 on a *.accdb database which I was given by the previous user.  Any ideas why this is happening?
I would imagine that it something to do with my print preview?

Comment: No idea. Would have to review the db. If you want to provide, upload to a fileshare site such as Box.com and post link. Or use a forum that allows attachment to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably there is VBA code behind the report that changes the text, e.g. in an `OnFormat` event that only runs in Print preview.

Open Design view, open the report's code module, and search for the text you see in Print preview.

Comment: I have looked but as far as I can see there are no VBA code behind the report. As an example, I was trying to change one word from Treasurer to Secretary. Display view shows Secretary but print preview still shows Treasurer.

Comment: Hm. In the VBA Editor, try a Global Search ("current project") for Treasurer. Otherwise, as June7 wrote, you could upload a sample database (stripped of personal data) to a file hoster.

Comment: OK I think that I have found the problem. The report is a standard letter to each member but depending on when they last paid their subs, one of three different sentences are substituted. I could not see anything in the events but as soon as I opened the VBA Editor all was revealed Thanks for steering me in the right direction.